# org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files

Tags: 18.04

I need some help with the PolicyKit1 thing.

I'm running mastodon (joinmastodon.org) on Ubuntu 18.04 server and I'm not able to start back the services.

When I run `systemctl start mastodon-web mastodon-sidekiq mastodon-streaming` I get this:

```
Failed to start mastodon-web.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mastodon-web.service' for details.
Failed to start mastodon-sidekiq.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mastodon-sidekiq.service' for details.
Failed to start mastodon-streaming.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mastodon-streaming.service' for details.
```

or, when I run this `systemctl enable mastodon-*` I get this

```
Failed to enable unit: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
```

I have no idea where this error come or how to fix it. I tried already a few things I found on StackEchange, but not help to fix it.

Please help me to make this go away. 
Thank You.

Comment: In my case it was an issue related to user rights: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158494/the-name-org-freedesktop-policykit1-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider to install the [package with needed *org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1):

```
sudo apt install policykit-1
```

Answer (score 33):

If you are not root, you will get the same error message even though `policykit-1` is installed. In this case, you may prefix the command with `sudo`.

Comment: This answer describes most likely cause of the terribly undescriptive error.